# @vitejs/plugin-legacy: polyfills vs modernPolyfills

Tags: vite

I am using Vite with CSR React app. I updated the app's dependencies recently to their latest version and everything is working well in development and production in modern browsers.

One of the app's dependencies is using `Object.hasOwn` and this has caused the following error to appear to some users which are using legacy browsers: `Object.hasOwn is not a function`.

In order to fix the issue I added the following setting to `@vitejs/plugin-legacy`:

```
plugins: [
  react(),
  legacy({
    targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11'],
    polyfills: ['es/object/has-own'],
  }),
],
```

However, this did not fix the issue and the error remained.

I updated the legacy plugin settings as follows:

```
plugins: [
  react(),
  legacy({
    targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11'],
    polyfills: ['es/object/has-own'],
    modernPolyfills: ['es/object/has-own'],
  }),
],
```

With this setting, the error seems to have been fixed in legacy browsers.

According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-legacy#readme), the `polyfills` setting is supposed to add the required `Object.hasOwn` polyfill when the app is loaded in legacy browsers. What I don't understand is why this did not work until I added the `modernPolyfills` setting.

What is the difference between `polyfills` and `modernPolyfills` in this case?

Comment: I think the legacy browsers you mention are not exactly legacy. They are the ones specified in modernTargets but don't support hasOwn. (like chrome >= 80 and <93) You need to polyfill for those, hence the modernPolyfills.

Comment: When we set `targets` to `['defaults', 'not IE 11']` doesn't this mean that `@vitejs/plugin-legacy` should provide legacy chunks and polyfills to all browsers that do not fall into this category? (which is practically: 'last 2 versions and not dead, > 0.3%, Firefox ESR, and not IE11'). Does having to include `modernPolyfills` mean that some of the modern browsers which fall into this category do not actually support `Object.hasOwn`?

Comment: Without `modernPolyfills` it will generate something like `<script nomodule src="/assets/polyfills-legacy...` -- this won't be executed on browsers which support `<script module`. Hence the browsers which support script module but don't support Object.hasOwn won't have it polyfilled.